# Shadows over Innistrad Starter Box

Tags: magic-the-gathering, ios, magic-duels

I completed the story mode for Shadows over Innistrad (Magic Duels on iOS), but never received the Starter Box. I raised the issue and they responded by giving me 300 coins, which would give me two boosters. Is that adequate? What exactly do you get in a Starter Box?

Comment: Since this question can only be answered by someone familiar with the computer game, I feel like you'd be more likely to get an answer on Arqade.

Comment: That being said, I would like to clarify that we do explicitly allow questions about computer implementations of board and card games.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked here because I saw what looked like Magic Duels questions here.. happy to move or delete the question if this isn't an appropriate venue. I did find my answer already though, which I will post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/magicduels/comments/5pz8hy/shadows_over_innistrad_starter_box/), I just had to spend those 300 coins on getting two Shadows Over Innistrad boosters, and the cards from the Starter Box were added to the collection automatically.